# Defining an XSD complexType with same attribute and element name

Tags: xml, xsd

How can I define a complexType in a XSD, which can have an attribute and an element with the same name?

For example:

```
<configuration>
   <configure name="variable1" value="val1"/>
   <configure name="variableList">
       <value>val1</value>
       <value>val2</value>
       <value>val3</value>
   </configure>
</configuration>
```

How could write an XSD for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing special has to be done to define an element that has an attribute with the same name as the element.  The following XSD will validate your XML:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="configuration">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="configure"
                    minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="value" type="xs:string"
                          minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:attribute name="value" type="xs:string"/>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

If you want the type of `configure` to vary based on the value of `name`, then use [conditional type assignment](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/#cTypeAlternative) (requires XSD 1.1), or, better, just differentiate the elements names themselves (works with XSD 1.0 and 1.1):

### XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
               xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="try.xsd">
   <configure name="variable1" value="val1"/>
   <configureList name="variable2">
       <value>val1</value>
       <value>val2</value>
       <value>val3</value>
   </configureList>
</configuration>
```

### XSD

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="configuration">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:element name="configure"
                    minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:attribute name="value" type="xs:string"/>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="configureList"
                    minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="value" minOccurs="0"
                          maxOccurs="unbounded"
                          type="xs:string"/>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string"/>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: But with this it's possible that `<configure..>` has an attribute value and a child element value in the same configure tag. If `<configure>` has an attribute value than its not allowed to define child elements value

Comment: Yes, I addressed that concern in the answer by mentioning conditional type assignment (XSD 1.1) or using different element names for the different cases (XSD 1.0 or 1.1).

Comment: e.g.: one element`<configure value=".." />` and another with `<configureList> <value>val</value>....</configureList>`, you mean like this?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean for the different element names solution.  I like that better than using conditional type assignment because it's simpler, doesn't require XSD 1.1, and follows the principle that elements with different requirements should be named differently.